# Is there any WordPress Plugin to User uploads file and share it?

Tags: file, upload, wordpress, share

Is there any WordPress Plugin for the users to upload files and share it?

the user upload an image, after upload complete, it must provide the url of the image... so he share it..

like file sharing sites https://www.speedyshare.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a plugin? Wordpress provides that funcionality.

Comment: the user(any visitor of the site) uploads a image and get the url of the image, so he can share it some other places... How??

Comment: Wordpress is a template to set up a blog, if you want a webpage that users upload images into your site and share it with someone, then you are not looking for a wordpress, you are looking for another thing. You can set up a blog, and...for example in another subdomain, you can set up another website to upload images and share it.